# Will a Thanksgiving Cactus Be Ok with 1-7-6 fertilizer?

Tags: fertilizer, holiday-cactus

I have a Thanksgiving cactus (*Schlumbergera truncata*) that I've had for maybe 5-6 years now. I recently picked up some ["Cactus Juice"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000ZOICVA) on sale in a local store, and was considering feeding it to my Thanksgiving cactus. [Some sites](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/cacti-succulents/christmas-cactus/christmas-cactus-fertilizer.htm) I've read said that I should feed it 10-10-10 or 20-20-20 fertilizer, but the Cactus juice is 1-7-6.

As a somewhat gardening novice who only vaguely understands that those numbers have to do with the nitrogen/phosphorous/potassium content, will the Cactus Juice be a good fertilizer for my Christmas cactus?

Answer (score 2):

It won't kill the plant, but it's not ideal for a Schlumbergia, which is a forest type cactus that flowers yearly. The Cactus Juice you bought appears to be formulated for most desert type cacti that grow slowly and flower occasionally, rather than one which grows a little faster and flowers regularly, so it's not a fertilizer I'd recommend for this particular plant.

Answer (score 2):

I believe so. I use "starter" 9 /45 / 15 on everything ( in moderation - no vegetables now) . Using the premise that the plant knows what it needs. My main Thanksgiving cactus is > 20 years old. ( Branches fall off and root in other pots).